# Will a single GSA search request that specifies two site collections get loaded into the suggestions database for both sites?

Tags: google-search-appliance

Will a single GSA search request that specifies two site collections get loaded into the suggestions database for both sites?

For example consider the following query,
http://gsa/search?q=hello&site=site1|site2&client=myfrontend

If results are returned from both collections will the query "hello" get loaded into the suggestion database for both,
1. client=myfrontend&site=site1
2. client=myfrontend&site=site2

So far I have not seen the query get loaded into either suggest database, but perhaps I have not waited long enough, which makes me wonder is there any way to quickly reset/reload suggestions? In the past I have tried resetting them via admin console's suggestions page, and then enabling/disabling suggestions via the frontend, but it does not always regenerate them. Is there any other procedure people follow to reload suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

Contacted Google support and, if multiple collections are defined in search request the suggestion gets logged to the default_collection.

They are working on a resolution :)